# Php - how to do multiple search w/ multiple output alternately?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a question regarding on multiple output alternately with only one search engine....I have this scenario below..

Scenario:

1. First search the data. The output will go in `textarea1(id='content')`
2. Second search the data. The output will go in `textarea2(id='content1')`
3. Third search the data. The output will go in `textarea3('content2')`

NOTE:I only used one search engine..

Please help me :(
Thank you and have a nice day!
Below is my code

Table: users

```
 CREATE TABLE users
 (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name VARCHAR(50),
 age INT)
```

index.php

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function get() {
        $.post('data.php', {
                name: form.search.value
            },
            function(output) {
                $('#content').html(output).show();
                $('#content1').html(output).show();
                $('#content2').html(output).show();
            });
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>
        <form name="form">
            <input type="text" name="search">
            <input type="button" value="Get" onClick="get();">
        </form>
        <div>
            <textarea id='content' cols='15' rows='5'></textarea>
            <textarea id='content1' cols='15' rows='5'></textarea>
            <textarea id='content2' cols='15' rows='5'></textarea>
        </div>
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

data.php

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

if($name==NULL)
echo "Please enter a name";

else{
$age = mysql_query("SELECT age FROM users WHERE memberName='$name'");
$age_num_rows = @mysql_num_rows($age);

if($age_num_rows==0)
echo "Name does not exists";

else
{
$age = mysql_result($age, 0);   
echo "$name's age is $age";
}
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not suppress errors when calling methods with the `@` operator. If something goes wrong you want to know about it and will need to take corrective action, display a useful message for the user, log the problem, or all that and more. It also makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated if you ignore errors that are trying to point out serious problems.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @tadman...